# How to escape from rhythmbox party mode?

Tags: 12.04, configuration, rhythmbox, window

I'm trapped in a party!

Is there a hotkey to recover normal rhythbox window mode (instead of whole-fullscreen)?

Or how to locate a config file of rhythmbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried pressing the <kbd>F11</kbd> key?

Answer (score 2):

A hotkey for switching between party mode is **F11**.

I had to terminate the rhythmbox process from `gnome-system-monitor`, then it started fullscreen - yet not covering Unity bar, launcher and window options. I was fine from there.

Comment: Well I didn't saw Your answer while typing mine, simple is that :) .

Comment: I've posted multiple answers today to find other folks also answered at more-or-less the same time.

Comment: Yeah... I don't mind anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Hold down {Alt} to click and drag the window. When you see the menu bar, choose View and unclick Party Mode. If it is not set on, set it on, then unclick it.

Comment: Thanks. Too bad pressing Alt does not open Rhythmbox window options, but it opens Unity command field (window-related I guess). Alt holding doesn't make anything there, yet it works fine for other windows. I handled it another way.

Comment: How? Inquiring minds want to know.